# Why does the Lanczos algorithm fail on repeated/multiple eigenvalues?

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm trying to code up the Lanczos algorithm for eigenvalue approximation at the moment. I've seen on pages like [this](http://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/etemplates/node106.html) that the algorithm can't distinguish the eigenvectors if the dimension of the eigenspace is >1, but I don't understand why this makes it actually fail rather than just finish incompletely.

When I run tests the algorithm breaks because it ends up dividing by 0 when trying to find the orthonormal basis. Can anyone direct me to a proof / show my why it fails?

Comment: But the link you posted does not say anything about the algorithm to fail and offers possible solutions in case of multiplicity. Your implementation probably “fails” because you do not handle correctly when it should stop.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel, that is not true unfortunately. The algorithm in practice does not fail as floating point arithmetic errors lets you avoid actually dividing by zero, but it seems to be a well known fact that under infinite precision the algorithm will indeed fail.

Comment: Of course, one has to be careful with the finite precision Lanczos algorithm. However, the only place where the [algorithm](http://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/etemplates/node104.html) divides is when normalizing the "residual" vector. If its norm is zero (or "tiny" in finite precision) this is perfectly fine and it indicates that the algorithm *should stop* because it "exhausted" the Krylov subspace and not because it "failed".

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel okay cool. Why does it divide by zero?

Comment: Because the implementation, of whatever *it* means, is wrong. There is probably, as a classic would say, a missing `if`. You did not include or link to any particular implementation.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel, I think you're misunderstanding my question. Obviously you can avoid having an issue by checking to see if a denominator is zero, it seems to me that this is an incredibly trivial announcement to make. My question was regarding the theory behind why the algorithm leads to this problem in the first place. In case you're interested, the primary reason is that an irreducible tridiagonal matrix of size n*n has rank >=n-1. If we have a repeated eigenvalue in A, there is also one in the tridiag matrix composed in the algorithm. Then the rank of T-k*I where k is the eigenvector must

Comment: be at most n-2, and so as T-kI is still a tridiagonal matrix we must have that it is not irreducible. This means that one of the off-diagonal entries is zero, and therefore an infinite-precision version of the lanczos algorithm will indeed divide by zero.

Comment: So is your question "why an irreducible tridiagonal matrix does not have repeated eigenvalues"?

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel this result essentially is the answer to my question however at the time I did not realise the relevance of that result.